# axis.extremes.userMin & userMax undefined on redraw with multiple charts

Tags: jquery, javascript, highcharts

I am trying to draw a **pie** chart on move of **highstock** slider.

At first move every thing is OK and I am getting values of highStock's `axis.extremes.userMin` & `userMax` as expected

### Code

```
    var extremes = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
    console.log(extremes);
    console.log(chart.xAxis[0]);
    console.log("userMin = " + extremes.userMin);
    console.log("userMax = " + extremes.userMax);
```

But once the pie chart is drawn I am getting above values as `undefined` as can be seen in console. What can be causing this Or how can I get the `userMin`/`userMax`?

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8nZr/1/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be overwriting your `chart` variable. [Use a different variable for the pie and the stock chart.](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8nZr/36/)

In your case, you may as well [use `this` inside the `chart.events.redraw`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.events.redraw) to point to the current (whose even is being handled) chart in your handler. [Demo @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8nZr/35/)

```
redraw: function (event) {
    if (this.xAxis) {
        var extremes = this.xAxis[0].getExtremes();    
        console.log(extremes);
        console.log(chart.xAxis[0]);
        console.log("userMin = " + extremes.userMin);
        console.log("userMax = " + extremes.userMax);
        drawPie();

    }
}
```

---

A better or more correct way to handle your use case would be attaching the handler to the [`xAxis.events.setExtremes`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes) event rather than the `chart.events.redraw` event since you want to do something on the slide of the slider.

As given in the documentation, the event object contains the new min and max values as `event.min` and `event.max` and `this` represents the axis inside the handler.
This is how your code would look like

```
       xAxis: [
            {
            events: {
                setExtremes: function(event) {
                        console.log(this);
                        console.log("userMin = " + event.min);
                        console.log("userMax = " + event.max);
                        drawPie();                       
                }
            }}
        ],
```

[Handling slider events @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/3Vypa/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling console.log before assigning the data to the series.

Could you please try calling console.log after you already assigned data to series?

```
series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
```

Mention this before you call console.log

Comment: my question here is after pie is drawn on "redraw" event of highstock  "userMin" & "userMax" is blank. before pie it is working fine. or if i remove call to function "drawPie()" , I am getting correct value of "userMin" & "userMax"