# Catch date(or time) while horizontal slider is moving in highstocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to find any mouse-move event during slider movement. I have to catch the date and show it in a div while the slider is moving.

I am using the `setExtremes()` method of highstock but it is not working.

Comment: You need to describe your problem much more clearly, show us some of your code and ask a question. http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Do you have any code? What have you tried? I don't understand the first statement. Are you finding mouse events are are you not finding any mouse events? There is no question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535594/highchart-and-highstock-together) is useful.

It suggests you need something along the following lines :

```
xAxis: [{
    events: {
        setExtremes: function(e) {
            $("#myDiv").text(Highcharts.dateFormat(null, e.min) + ' : ' + Highcharts.dateFormat(null, e.max));
        }
    }
}],
```

### EDIT

I've just tried [the fiddle referenced from the API on this subject](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/events-setextremes/), and unfortunately the `xAxis.events.setExtremes` event fires after the horizontal slider has been released, which is too late.

After a goodly hunt through the API for an event that fires at the right time, I am forced to conclude that, either :

- this feature is provided very obscurely, by some means other than external event handling
- this feature is not included and you would need to hack the Highcharts source to add it.